# How can I put the arrow with the 0 in this diagram?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Here is the diagram I want to draw:

> [image]

I got a help on drawing the following from here :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}
    $$\begin{tikzcd}
        & P \ar[dl, dashed, "\tilde{f}" ']
        \ar[d, "f"]     \\
        A \ar[r,twoheadrightarrow,"g" ']    & B 
    \end{tikzcd}$$
\end{document}
```

But how can I put the arrow with the 0 in this diagram? could someone show me this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}
    \[\begin{tikzcd}
        & P \ar[dl, dashed, "\tilde{f}" ']
        \ar[d, "f"]     \\
        A \ar[r,twoheadrightarrow,"g" ']   & B  \arrow[r, twoheadrightarrow] & 0
    \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use `$$` in LaTeX! Instead them use `\[` and `\]` respectively.

Answer (score 7):

The original figure, I think, it is done with [xy](/questions/tagged/xy) package. In fact the classic tips are the same. The font used it is ([mtpro2](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html)) where in this [link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite) you can find the version lite.

I have changed the font with `newtxtext` (clone of Times New Roman) and `newtxmath`. I think that it is very close with your image.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=2pc@C=3pc{
& P \ar[d]^{id} \ar@{-->}[dl]_{\mu} &\\
M \ar[r]^{\varphi} & P\ar[r] & 0
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Addendum 1: ## To have the twoheadrightarrow you can use the code `\ar@{>>}` (see the MWE):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=2pc@C=3pc{
& P \ar[d]^{id} \ar@{-->}[dl]_{\mu} &\\
M \ar@{>>}[r]^{\varphi} & P\ar@{>>}[r] & 0
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the tips of [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd) you can use the options `[all, cmtip]`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=2pc@C=3pc{
& P \ar[d]^{id} \ar@{-->}[dl]_{\mu} &\\
M \ar@{>>}[r]^{\varphi} & P\ar@{>>}[r] & 0
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another possible answer than @Roland's, would be to use `\usetikzlibrary{matrix}`. That would look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \matrix[matrix of math nodes,row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]{%
            && |(P)| P \\
            & |(M)| M & |(Ptwo)| P & |(zero)| 0 \\
        };%
        \draw[dashed,->,very thick](P)--(M) node[above,pos=0.5]{\(\mu\)};%
        \draw[->>,very thick](P)--(Ptwo) node[right,pos=0.5]{id};%
        \draw[->>,very thick](M)--(Ptwo) node[above,pos=0.5]{\(\varphi\)};%
        \draw[->,very thick](Ptwo)--(zero);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

That would give the display:

[image]

> Nota Bene: You can play around and change `[row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]` to modify the spacing and make it as you wish.